# How to manually ack/nack a PubSub message in Camel Route

Tags: apache-camel, google-cloud-pubsub

I am setting up a Camel Route with ackMode=NONE meaning acknowlegements are not done automatically. How do I explicitly acknowledge the message in the route?

In my Camel Route definition I've set ackMode to NONE. According to the documentation, I should be able to manually acknowledge the message downstream:

https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-google-pubsub/src/main/docs/google-pubsub-component.adoc

"AUTO = exchange gets ack’ed/nack’ed on completion. NONE = downstream process has to ack/nack explicitly"

However I cannot figure out how to send the ack.

```
from("google-pubsub:<project>:<subscription>?concurrentConsumers=1&maxMessagesPerPoll=1&ackMode=NONE")
                .bean("processingBean");
```

My PubSub subscription has an acknowledgement deadline of 10 seconds and so my message keeps getting re-sent every 10 seconds due to ackMode=NONE. This is as expected. However I cannot find a way to manually acknowledge the message once processing is complete and stop the re-deliveries.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to dig through the Camel components and figure out how it is done. First I created a `GooglePubSubConnectionFactory` bean:

```
@Bean
    public GooglePubsubConnectionFactory googlePubsubConnectionFactory() {
        GooglePubsubConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new GooglePubsubConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setCredentialsFileLocation(pubsubKey);
        return connectionFactory;
    }
```

Then I was able to reference the ack id of the message from the header:

```
@Header(GooglePubsubConstants.ACK_ID) String ackId
```

Then I used the following code to acknowledge the message:

```
List<String > ackIdList = new ArrayList<>();
        ackIdList.add(ackId);
        AcknowledgeRequest ackRequest = new AcknowledgeRequest().setAckIds(ackIdList);
        Pubsub pubsub = googlePubsubConnectionFactory.getDefaultClient();
        pubsub.projects().subscriptions().acknowledge("projects/<my project>/subscriptions/<my subscription>", ackRequest).execute();
```

Comment: Hi @Graham,can you please give full code for this I have a similar requirement but get  error `@Header not applicable to field` on 

`@Header(GooglePubsubConstants.ACK_ID) String ackId`

I am using Camel 2.24

Comment: I'm using Camel 3.0 so maybe due to that?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is best if you look how the Camel component does it with `ackMode=AUTO`. Have a [look at this class](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-google-pubsub/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/google/pubsub/consumer/PubsubAcknowledgement.java) (method `acknowledge`)

But why do you want to do this extra work? Camel is your fried to simplify integration by abstracting away low level code.

So when you use **`ackMode=AUTO`** Camel **automatically commits your successfully processed messages** (when the message has successfully passed the whole route) **and rolls back your not processable messages**.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The thing is I want to acknowledge the message before the whole route has completed. Using ackMode=AUTO means if the route ultimately fails then my message will be re-queued which I don't necessarily want. I want to control when my message get re-queued depending on what the exception is.