# Manual ack Google pubsub messages from Apache Camel route

Tags: java, apache-camel, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a main Camel Route(Poller) which starts from Google PubSub component and calls a secondary route that goes to an HTTP endpoint. If I get any exceptions such as Network or Endpoint down (HTTP 500, 400 etc) then I don't want the message to be nACKED instead I want all messages to be ACKed regardless of whether the route succeeds.

I am looking at options to ACK regardless of route outcome. So far not able to find any methods or Props on Exchange etc.

I know this is not ideal but I have a requirement this way. I have tried using a custom pubsub connection factory like in thisquestion ([How to manually ack/nack a PubSub message in Camel Route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57749818/how-to-manually-ack-nack-a-pubsub-message-in-camel-route)) but it doesn't seem to help in my case as I still don't seem to be able to ack them back.

Any ideas on how I can do this or any examples that can help me. Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure about changing Camel Route, but you can regularly purge old messages from your subscription using the techniques described here: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/replay-overview This accomplishes the objective of dropping messages that were not processed within a period of time

Answer (score 0):

Supposedly this should work:

Add a processor in your Camel route that does this:

```
exchange.getUnitOfWork().done(exchange);
```

It should ack the message regardless of the source (google pubsub in this case)...